# How to localize a string with formatting placeholders?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, stringwithformat

I need to translate text in controller.body

My code:

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n"
                                                    "Label 1: %@ \n"
                                                    "Label 2: %@ \n"
                                                    "Label 3: %@ \n"
                                                    "Label 4: %@", label1.text, label2.text, label3.text, label4.text];
```

I have file Localizable.strings, how can I localize a string with formatting placeholders? I mean that text "Label 1", "Label 2" etc...

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on localization: http://www.delitestudio.com/2012/09/11/how-to-internationalize-an-os-x-ios-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `NSLocalizedString`

your `localizable.string` will look like

```
"Label 1: %@ \n" = "your label";
"Label 2: %@ \n" = "your label";
//And so on...
```

And your code

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n",
                                             NSLocalizedString(@"Label 1: %@ \n", nil),
                                             NSLocalizedString(@"Label 2: %@ \n", nil),
                                             etc....];
```

Comment: where? what the problem you faced?

Comment: here: NSLocalizedString("Label 1: %@ \n", nil),

Comment: add a comma before it [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n",
                                             NSLocalizedString("Label 1: %@ \n", nil), other labels....];

Comment: now this problem: Incompatible pointer types sending 'char [7]' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

Answer (score 0):

Something this for localize string

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Label 1: %@ ," , @"Label 2: %@ ,", @"Label 3: %@ ," , @"Label 4: %@ ,"), label1.text,label2.text,label3.text,label4.text]
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern:

```
NSString* stringFormat = NSLocalizedString (@"LabelStringFormat", ...);
NSString* labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:stringFormat, label1.text, ...];
```

and in your localised.strings

```
"LabelStringFormat" = "Label 1: %@, ...";
```

You can even re-order the items without code by using the right string format.